# replacing field in Oracle SQL with join not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and I have to update the following SQL to display the clients "title" as the first field and the count as the 2nd field just like it is now.  If you look at the following SQL is what I have now and it runs great but can someone please show me how to add the title from client table"

**SQL:**

```
select   SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) -1) AS FILENAME, 
COUNT   (SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4)-1)) AS DOWNLOADS 
FROM access_log where id = 5555 and time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2014/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE ('2014/10/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) -1) 
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

**Tables:**

```
Table name: access_log
Col name: activity 
Value: Download file:/webdocs/data/groupXXX/case/03_28_54_9_0000011856.pdf
Col name: id
Value: 5555

Table name: client
Col name: id
Value: 5555
Col name: title
Value: dj cafe
```

please help me if you can...

it should be something like this

```
**TITLE|DOWNLOADS
dj cafe|22**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to produce a result set drawing from more than one table, then you must perform an appropriate join on the tables involved.  What makes a join "appropriate" is measured mostly by the join predicate, as judged in light of the relationship between the tables.  In your case, if tables `access_log` and `client` are related through their respective `id` fields (which would be a little strange) then this query would do the job:

```
SELECT   
  client.title AS TITLE, 
  COUNT(SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4)-1)) AS DOWNLOADS 
FROM
  access_log
  JOIN client
    ON client.id = access_log.id
WHERE
  client.id = 5555
  AND time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2014/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE ('2014/10/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
GROUP BY SUBSTR(activity, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) + 1, INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 5) - INSTR(activity, '/', 1, 4) -1) 
ORDER BY DOWNLOADS DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `client` value in other table's column, you need to `join` the two `tables` on column `ID`.  And include the column name ID in the `select` list with proper `table alias`.

Something like,

`table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)`

Make sure you include the columns of select list in the `group by` clause too.

You are almost close writing the required SQL, just implement the suggestion to get your desired output.